# MediaEvent: MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed"}

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

When I load .js file using android webview its show me below error when I click player button to play radio music file contains in the javascript file.

```
chromium: [ERROR:render_media_log.cc(30)] MediaEvent: MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed"}
chromium: [ERROR:render_media_log.cc(30)] MediaEvent: PIPELINE_ERROR DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN
```